# Ordering the same thing again, would I use "再來"?

Tags: equivalent-phrase, phrase-request

In a bar/café/etc say I've finished my drink and want to order another, what idiomatic ways are there to order another one the same?

Would it involve 再來 as Google Translate suggests but other web searches don't seem to back up?

Is 請再來一杯拿鐵 idiomatic? If not, what do people actually say? Something involving 回 or 同樣 maybe?

In English I wouldn't necessarily use the word "same" but I think I'd probably always use "another". If I've been sitting right at the bar near the same bartender I might say "same again please" but not in a café when I've been far away for half an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order the same thing again, the basic form is [再來(again/ additionally)+number+classifier+noun], therefore, 再來一杯拿鐵 is correct

You can often omit the object in conversation,  so 再來一杯 would be enough.

More example:

再來一打生蠔 = Give me another dozen oysters

再來四支啤酒 = Bring me four more beers

If you have done fifty pushups already and your instructor said 再來五十下掌上壓 (again fifty times pushup), that means "do 50 more pushups "

If your instructor wants you to run 400M and then do 50 pushups, he can say 先跑四百米，再來五十下掌上壓 (first run 400M, then do fifty pushups